# How to trigger a javascript function when enter is pressed in a textbox

Tags: javascript

I have the following HTML code:

```
    <nav>
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <form>
            <div class="input-field">
            <input id="username_entry" type="search" placeholder="Enter Last.fm username" required>
            <label class="label-icon" for="search"><i class="material-icons">search</i></label>
            <i class="material-icons">close</i>
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

How can I create a Javascript function that will execute when the user presses the enter key?

All I seem to be able to find is examples where a button is used and you simply simulate the clicking of the button. For example,

```
// Get the input field
var input = document.getElementById("myInput");

// Execute a function when the user releases a key on the keyboard
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  // Number 13 is the "Enter" key on the keyboard
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    // Cancel the default action, if needed
    event.preventDefault();
    // Trigger the button element with a click
    document.getElementById("myBtn").click();
  }
});
```

I don't want to place a button on the page and if I remove it and try to just execute a command, it doesn't work.

```
// Get the input field
var input = document.getElementById("username_entry");

// Execute a function when the user releases a key on the keyboard
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  // Number 13 is the "Enter" key on the keyboard
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    console.log("it worked!");
  }
});
```

If I type something into the search box and hit enter, nothing is printed to the console. Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong? Please don't hesitate to ask if I can clarify my question.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: If your `input` is in a `form` the default behaviour when pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> is submiting the form. That cause the page to unload, essentially resetting **everything**.

Comment: @connexo interesting, so I removed the form tags and it worked. The issue now is that it only works once. If I enter something in the box and hit enter for a second time, nothing happens. Thank you by the way for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `input` is in a `form`, the default behaviour when pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> is *submitting* the form. That causes the page to **unload**, essentially **resetting everything**.

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.key === 'Enter') {
    console.log('You pressed Enter');
  }
})

document.querySelector('form input').addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.key === 'Enter') {
    console.log('You pressed Enter');
  }
})

document.querySelector('form + form input').addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.key === 'Enter') {
    event.preventDefault(); // this prevents the submit on Enter
    console.log('You pressed Enter');
  }
})
```

```css
input { width: 300px; }
```

```html
<input placeholder="I'm not in a form." />

<form>
  <input placeholder="I'm in a form."  />
</form>

<form>
  <input placeholder="I'm in a form. Enter default gets prevented"  />
</form>
```

That is why you need to do `event.preventDefault()` in your key handler.

Comment: Thank you so much for your clear explanation. I truly appreciate your time and will set it as the correct answer as soon as the time requirement is met. Thanks again!